# Android studio - Draw a line on a canvas with preview, without having all the former lines drawn on the canvas?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MyCanvasView extends View {

    public final int BRUSH_FREE = 0;
    public final int BRUSH_LINE = 1;

    private int brush_mode;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mBackroundPaint;
    private Path mPath;
    private int mDrawColor;
    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mTestColor;
    private Canvas mExtraCanvas;
    private Bitmap mExtraBitmap;
    private Rect mFrame;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyCanvasView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyCanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        mBackgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                R.color.opaque_orange, null);
        mDrawColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                R.color.opaque_yellow, null);
        mTestColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.testColor,null);

        brush_mode = BRUSH_FREE;

        mPath = new Path();

        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setColor(mDrawColor);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mBackroundPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
        mBackroundPaint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height,
                                 int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
        mExtraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mExtraCanvas = new Canvas(mExtraBitmap);
        mExtraCanvas.drawColor(mBackgroundColor);


        int inset = 40;
        mFrame = new Rect (inset, inset, width - inset, height - inset);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        canvas.drawBitmap(mExtraBitmap, 0, 0, null);


        canvas.drawRect(mFrame, mPaint);
    }


    private float mX, mY;
    private float moveLastX = -10000, moveLastY = -10000;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;



    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            switch (brush_mode){
                case (BRUSH_FREE):
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                    paths.add(mPath);
                    mExtraCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                    break;
                case (BRUSH_LINE):
                    if(x != moveLastX && y != moveLastY) {
                        mPath.moveTo(moveLastX, moveLastY);
                        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                        mExtraCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mBackroundPaint);
                        mPath.lineTo(x, y);
                        mExtraCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        moveLastX = -10000;
        moveLastY = -10000;
        mPath.reset();
    }



    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(moveLastY == -10000 && moveLastX == -10000){
                    moveLastX = x;
                    moveLastY = y;
                }
                touchMove(x, y);
                moveLastY = y;
                moveLastX = x;
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                break;
            default:

        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    public static int getScreenHeight() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }

    public void clearMyCanvas(){
        mExtraCanvas.drawColor(mBackgroundColor);
        mExtraCanvas.drawRect(mFrame, mPaint);
        invalidate();
        Log.d("MY ALERTS","Path reset supposedly");
    }

    public void setBrush_mode(int brushtype){
        switch (brushtype){
            case(BRUSH_FREE):
                brush_mode = BRUSH_FREE;
                break;
            case(BRUSH_LINE):
                brush_mode = BRUSH_LINE;
                break;

        }
    }



}
```

I want the finger to drag across the screen, and have a preview of the line show from the fixed start position (of when the finger initially touched the screen) to where it currently is. Problem is I am having trouble getting rid of all the preview lines drawn on screen so I'm getting this "sun-like" figure on the screen, where more and more lines are drawn with each and every move of the finger.
Can you help me organize a certain algorithm to do that properly?